# Setting primary key for two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, primary-key

How to set some_id
column in a table which is integer to be a primary key for two different tables? some_id is a column of a second table, but doesn't exist in the first one. Do I need to add some_id in the first table too and how to connect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to have a foreign key to another table you'll need that column's primary key as a field.

For example 
Table A: books

```
id
name
author_id
```

Table B: authors

```
id
first_name
last_name
```

If you created books without a reference to authors you can write a migration to have it added.

Run this command from the terminal while in your project's directory:

`rails g migration add_author_id_to_books`

This will create a migration which you can edit using your favorite text editor.

Your finished migration would look something like this:

```
class AddAuthorIdToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :books, :author, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

To finish things off update your models to reflect the relationships.

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authors
end
```

author.rb

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Note: this is Rails 4 syntax. If you're using an older version see the documentation specific to your version. In older versions the FK syntax is not as nice and you may even need a gem to get FKs to work properly.

Comment: Great, thanks! Just one question, I saw that some people are using self.primary_key = "some_id" in both models? Is there a difference between your solution and this?

Comment: My understanding of `primary_key` is that you only need to use it if you want to override your primary key. For me I leave all tables with a primary key column just called `id`. This is the way Rails likes you to do it and doing things the Rails way usually leads to a happier experience. If you found my answer helpful would you mind selecting it? It will help others with the same question in the future. Thanks!